# Ubuntu 16.04.1 does not detect AES-NI on my cpu

Tags: kernel, intel, cpu, architecture, cpuinfo

I recently upgraded my CPU from a [Pentium B950](http://ark.intel.com/products/55627/Intel-Pentium-Processor-B950-2M-Cache-2_10-GHz) to an [i5-2520M](http://ark.intel.com/products/52229/Intel-Core-i5-2520M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_20-GHz). The intel page says that my new CPU supports their aes extensions, but both `/etc/cpuinfo` and `cpuid` say that it doesn't. Other than that, everything is recognized and works fine. I've reinstalled the kernel and checked for BIOS updates, but it didn't help and there were none, respectively. Can anybody help?

Edit: Fixed links. This is on an Asus x54h, which will be 6 years old this christmas, so manufacturer support is out the window.

Comment: 1) Which system are we talking about (laptop model)? 2) Have you looked at your BIOS settings to see if you can enable AES-NI support? 3) You link to a "Intel Pentium B950" rather than a i5-2520M

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that installing the latest version of intel-microcode did not help, either that processor really doesn't have AES-NI (Intel ARK is known to get this kind of thing wrong sometimes), or it was disabled by the BIOS.

Contact your system vendor for support for a BIOS update that doesn't disable AES.  Alternatively, talk to people in the BIOS modding scene.